# What could be the reason for Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

hi all i am getting below error

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:331:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:662:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:146:12)
    at fn (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:896:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:325:12)
    at View.render (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:527:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:900:7)
    at /Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/app.js:57:9
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:58:5)`

Could any one tell me what could be the reason for it.My code is

```
router.post('/readCSVFile',function(req,res){

if(typeof req.files.fileCSV === 'undefined'){
    var err = {message: 'Please Select CSV file'};
    res.render('error', {message: err.message,error: err});
}

    var reader = yaCSV.createCsvFileReader(req.files.fileCSV.path,{
        'separator':',', 'quote':'"', 'escape':'"'
    });

    reader.addListener('data',function(data){
        var json = createJsonObject(data);
        _data.push(json);
        });

    reader.addListener('error',function(err){
        console.error("err.status " + err.status);
        //err.status = 500;
        //res.status(500);
        err.message = 'Select the proper CSV file';
        res.render('error', {message: err.message,error: err});
        console.error(util.inspect(err));
    });
    reader.addListener('end', function() {
        res.render('renderCSV',{data: _data});
    });
    var _data = [];
```

});

Comment: As far as I know, when you call `response.render` it sends the complete HTTP response. So if you call it again as you do in some code paths in your code, it gives you this error because it cannot send another set of HTTP response headers because it already started writing to the response body.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "return" statement after each "res.render" command.

Comment: Hi takinola..It is working for the 1st case i.e when the 'req.files.fileCSV' undefined but for the case when there is an error while processing the csv file that time it is not.It is still throwing an error which i mentioned above even after adding the return.Just want to understand why is it throwing this error as response is created on condition based.The code would be coming to 'end' callback when it will be done with all the processing of CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out why it was not working for me.I was getting multiple errors in callback function which was registered for errors in 'ya-csv'.So as i have already sent the response for one.my code was trying to send the response for the 2nd as well and hence the error.I sorted it out by putting and if condition and making it for one.

Thanks 
-Learner